# Is there any way to list the latest GUI transactions in Linux?

Tags: command-line, files, command-history

Suppose that I've moved a directory in my `Xfc` desktop in another directory, which I can't remember the name of the destination directory.

Is there any way to list the latest transactions in terminal, in order to find the name of that directory?

Answer (score 3):

If you've logged out since that session, look in `.bash_history` in your home directory (`~`). It contains all commands issued in earlier sessions, which is by default 500 lines. You have to log out first for `.bash_history` to be updated. If you don't want to log out first in the future, look at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67283/is-it-possible-to-make-writing-to-bash-history-immediate) that makes writing to `.bash_history` immediate.

Comment: It seems that `.bash_history` shows the terminal commands not what I've done in GUI manually.

Comment: @Kasramvd there isn't a default solution for that. If you've lost a file and remember the name of it, you can always use the `find` command.

Comment: I didn't lose the file, just don't knew what was the file name that I dragged and dropped I thought maybe there was a way or at least a tools fro that. :), however thanks for your reply.